Make Staging Ground posts, comments, and history available in SEDE
Please put Staging Ground items in the dbo.Posts table, and their comments in dbo.Comments, and their timelines in dbo.PostHistory (including events (and their types in dbo.PostHistoryTypes) like various review actions, going inactive, the various types of publishing).
I imagine that this wouldn't be too too difficult. I have a feeling that a lot of the data model is similar to existing stuff, given that a lot of the frontend seems shared (Ex. post body rendering, edit UI rendering, timeline rendering), and site://q/<id> works.
Just to give some taste of motivation, this would enable the community to do their own "research" queries into SG whenever they want. For example, some of the things I'm interested in are:

In the average time window, how many items are new, pending changes, or pending review?
How long does the average item stay in each state? Is the ball more often waiting in the asker's court? Or the reviewers'?
How do items finish? What portion auto-publish? What portion go inactive / stale?
Which comment templates are used the most?
Are there common patterns in the content of posts that auto-publish?

